# Efficient way to generate random variable $X$ having density function $f(x) = \frac{20} {0.03078} x^3(1-x), 0 < x < 0.3$

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, random-variables

What's an efficient way to generate random variable $X$ having density function $$f(x) = \frac{20} {0.03078} x^3(1-x), 0 < x < 0.3$$

Note this is a beta function conditioned on $[0,0.3]$. How should I implement the rejection method to complete this problem? I've tried breaking up the region into several subintervals and then using the rejection method, but this has no boost in the efficiency

Is there some clever function I can use as $g(x)$ to then generate a random $U$ ~ Uniform(0,1) variable and then compare $U$ to $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Edit: I first used $g(x) = 1/0.3, 0<x<0.3$. So then $c = max(f(x)/g(x)) = 3.68421054$. So my first method was generating $U_1$~Unif(0,1) and setting $Y = 0.3U_1$ ~ Unif(0,0.3). Then, I generated $U_2$~Unif(0,1). If $U_2 < \frac{f(Y)}{(3.68421054/0.3)}$, I accepted $X = Y$. Else repeated

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Random_variate_generation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: @D.W. I know those methods. I just haven't found an efficient rejection sampling case, or an function that bounds f(x) well that has an inverse as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show (1) what are the criteria/requirements for an answer to count as satisfactory, (2) what approaches you've already considered, and (3) why you've rejected them.  The reason why you reject a method should be directly connected to your criteria/requirements; if not, that is a sign that you need to revise your criteria/requirements.  This helps us make sure we're not repeating information you already know, helps answerers avoid wasting their time, and helps voters know how to evaluate proposed answers.

Comment: "Clever" is a matter of opinion and not a suitable requirement/criteria.  I don't know what "no boost in the efficiency" means, and specifically what alternative you are comparing to, or how you measure efficiency.

Comment: See what the distribution of $U^{1/4}$ gets you.

Comment: @Aruralreader Thanks!